# tableView background image hides activity indicator

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I'm setting the `backgroundView` of a tableView like this:

```
self.tableView.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background"]];
```

It works but gets placed on top of the tableview's activity indicator and hides it when the tableview is pulled down for refresh. I've tried setting a breakpoint on the point it's added and confirmed that indeed it goes on top of the activity indicator subviews array. Is there any way to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like a framework bug to be honest. What if you place a UIImageView with the background below the table, does that get the effect you want?

Comment: if i am right. your activity indicator is not clear / invisible because of background image. is it?

Comment: Tiago, I cannot place it below the table. Maybe it's because it's in a TableViewController. It just allows me to put it at the cells level which takes cell space.

Comment: Zubair, yes, that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that is better to place `UIImageView` below your `UITableView` and set:

```
_yourTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
```